# How do I check if the input() is in a given interval?

Tags: python

```
x = int(input("Start: "))
y = int(input("End: "))
z = range (x,y)
print (z)
Interval_1= range(1, 5)
Interval_2 = range (6, 8)
Interval_3 = range (9, 10)

if z in Interval_1:
  print ("Number is in Interval 1") 
else: ("Number is not in Interval 1")
```

I want the user to enter 2 numbers and to a given interval it should check whether it is in the interval or not but it seems like the code does not even run the if query. Is it because of the "in" command?

Comment: It may _appear_ not to run the query because of the missing `print`. You just have a string literal in parentheses, which is a valid expression but not one that does anything useful.

Comment: Some terminology: `z in Interval_1` is called the if condition. `in` is called an operator.

Comment: It might help to fix the formatting of your code to see what the problem is. Usually `else` is on its own line. If you do this, then jonrsharpe's suggestion becomes more obvious.

Comment: `x in range(...)` is only true if `x` is a number in the range. It can't be used to tell if one range is a subset of another range.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Sorry, what are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to check that `z` is a subsequence of `Interval_1`? If so then why does the code say "number"? And what are `Interval_2` and `Interval_3` for? Please make a [mre] including example input, desired output, and actual output. For more tips, see [ask]. You can [edit].

Comment: `in` with ranges only works with integers. otherwise you're checking to see whether a range object is in a range of integers, which it isn't.

Comment: Ranges can overlap in several ways. Which do you care about? If the input range is `0-10`, is it in all three intervals? Or do you only care if it is *contained* within the hard-coded intervals?

Comment: ok i might to understand the problem with the "in" but what could be an alternative to this? i just want to check if the users input is in any of the interval ranges i've created

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to check if a range is a part of another range in Python 3.x](/q/32480423/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code. It checks whether the start and end are in interval or not and outputs accordingly.

```
x = int(input("Start: "))
y = int(input("End: "))
z = range (x,y)
print (z)
Interval_1= range(1, 5)
Interval_2 = range (6, 8)
Interval_3 = range (9, 10)

if z[0] in Interval_1 and z[-1] in Interval_1:
    print ("Number is in Interval 1") 
elif z[0] in Interval_2 and z[-1] in Interval_2:
    print ("Number is in Interval 2") 
elif z[0] in Interval_3 and z[-1] in Interval_3:
    print ("Number is in Interval 3") 
else:
    print("Number is not in any of the intervals")
```

Comment: it worked but why did you use z[0] and z[-1]?

Comment: @kira_prz `z[0]` is the first element (i.e **x**) in the range and `z[-1]` is the last element in the range.

Comment: @kira_prz I have edited my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether one range is included in another, you can convert them both to sets and then test if one is a subset of the other:

```
if set(z) <= set(Interval_1):
    print("Number is in Interval 1")
else:
    print("Number is not in Interval 1")
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to solve something that could be handled by a few simple inequalities on the range boundaries.

Comment: I was about to add that, but just realized that it won't work correctly for ranges with different steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check `range.start` and `range.stop` like so:

```
x = int(input("Start: "))
y = int(input("End: "))
Interval_1= range(1, 5)

if Interval_1.start <= x < y <= Interval_1.stop:
  print ("Number is in Interval 1") 
else:
    print("Number is not in Interval 1")
```

This assumes the step is 1, and start is smaller than end.

Comment: `<` should be `<=`.

Comment: @Barmar I assume "End" is inclusive, he didn't really give a specification but it sounds reasonable for it to be inclusive.

Comment: But it isn't, because he does `z = range(x, y)`, and that's exclusive.

Comment: @Barmar no clue mate

Answer (score 0):

If you need absolutely robust code and don't mind it being slow, you can check every element individually to see if it's in the range.

```
if all(item in Interval_1 for item in z):
```

This works even if the ranges you're testing against have a step.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `in` or `not in` operator for a type (or class) in Python, that class should have the method `__contains__(self, item)`, the range object does have that method, but it only checks a single value in the range or not.

eg.

```py
>>> r = range(1,10)
>>> 8 in r
True
>>> 11 in r
False
```

However, your use case is different, you want to check if a `range` object `ra` in another `range` object `rb`. You may need to consider wrap ther standard `range` object, and create a `MyRange` to have this feature. Here is an example of a custom `range`.

```py
class MyRange(object):
    def __init__(self, start: int, end: int):
        self._start = start
        self._end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return range(self._start, self._end).__iter__()

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item._start >= self._start and item._end <= self._end


def main():
    base_range = MyRange(10, 20)

    in_range = MyRange(11, 19)

    out_range = MyRange(9, 15)

    for x in base_range:
        print(x)

    print(in_range in base_range) # True
    print(out_range in base_range) # False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```